# ORDER BY сортировка

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть массив товаров, как отсортировать данные при условии

Если заполнено поле status (!=0) значит by rating, далее by price

```
 ORDER BY (p.status > 0) DESC, p.price
```

Вот это условие выводит данные в виде если заполнено status то сначала их а потом по цене, оно не подходит так как нужно если заполнено status сортировать по rating далее выводить по цене.

Comment: *Вот это условие выводит данные в виде если заполнено status то сначала их а потом по цене,* Неправда. Плохо смотрите - надо быть внимательнее. Это условие делит все записи на три группы, выводимые одна за другой - в первую попадают все положительные значения, во вторую все остальные, кроме NULL, которые попадают в третью группу. В каждой группе записи независимо от остальных групп сортируются по цене.

Comment: *нужно если заполнено status сортировать по rating далее выводить по цене.* Пока что ваша задача выглядит как "я пока и сам до конца не знаю...". Значительная часть возможных вариантов - не описывается! Тогда как вы должны всё расписать абсолютно исчерпывающе,  так, чтобы любой прочитавший для любого набора мог, не задавая ни единого вопроса, правильно построить нужный порядок записей.

Answer (score 0):

Проверить наличие `p.status` можно изначально в `WHERE`. И сортировать уже по `rating`:

```
WHERE p.status > 0 ORDER BY rating ...
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Не совсем, так как применять это дело нужно только к 1 сортировке и написать нужно одним условием ...